# Kirchhoff's loop equation when there's a current source in it?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current-source, kirchhoffs-laws

How do you get the loop equation (using Kirchhoff's 2nd law) if there's a current source in it?
I mean, does the voltage after the current source decrease or increase?

Example:

[image: figure1]

I'm talking about loops B & C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you don't use kirchoff's voltage law on the loops containing current sources,, you merge two  loops like in the following image, this way you get two equations and third equation becomes   ib-ic = Iy,
[image]

Comment: So it's not possible at all with the current source? what are iA, iB, iC ?

Comment: current source's voltage is independent of its current, so you can not use a relation between i and V to put into kirchoff's voltage equation,

Comment: ia , ib and ic are loop currents,

Comment: so your three equations become,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Vx = (ia-ic)R1 + (ia-ib)R3,,,,,,,

0  = (ib-ia)R3 + (ic-ia)R1 + (ic)R2 + (ib)R4,,,,,,,,

Iy = ic - ib,,,,,
solve for ia, ib and ic,,and you have solved the circuit i.e, you can calculate voltage drop across each element and current through each element

Comment: one more question, how do you find out ia, ib, ic ??

Comment: you have three linear equations,, just solve them,,name the equations 1,2 and 3,  put value of ic from equation 3 into equations 1 and 2 to get new equations 4 and 5,, then put value of ib from equation 5 into equation 4, you'll get the value of ia,,put this value in equation 4, you'll get value of ib and then put value of ib in equation 3 to get value of ic, or you can solve it using matrices, this link shows how to solve a circuit using mesh analysis, http://utwired.engr.utexas.edu/rgd1/lesson07.cfm

Answer (score 3):

You probably know that the nodal analysis can't be done on circuits with voltage sources. Instead, we have to create "supernodes" around each voltage source and do the *modified nodal analysis*.

Loop analysis (aka [*mesh analysis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh_analysis)) is the dual of nodal analysis. And it can not be done on a circuit containing a current source that appears in two meshes. Instead, we create a "supermesh" from elements of the two meshes that meet at the current source, and add an extra equation for the source itself.

Answer (score -1):

You can get a set of modified loop equations for a given circuit by using the following Algorithm
Algorithm
•   Keep all independent voltage sources unchanged
•   Keep all impedances unchanged
•   Replace all the independent current sources by unknown voltage sources.   For each independent current source include an extra equation of the form
“Algebraic sum of the relevant loop currents = Current output”
•   Replace all the controlled sources by unknown voltage sources.   Control laws are used to get the necessary extra equations.
Details of the method including example is available in
Reference : A. K. Bandyopadhyay, "AUGMENTED LOOP EQUATION TECHNIQUE AND ITS APPLICATION"
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/317639342_AUGMENTED_LOOP_EQUATION_TECHNIQUE_AND_ITS_APPLICATION

Comment: Formatting this question would be appropriate